# bootstrap.js error on IE 8 line 209 usinf twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but using IE 8, I get the following from error in bootstrap.js...

Webpage error details
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 292
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI:

```
    (http://74.54.89.128/~infinite/live_site/)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: You are calling jQuery twice. Maybe it is related.

Comment: As far as I can see, I'm only loading it once. I did have two separate noConflict includes, so I've removed one , and bootstrap just isn't doing the layout....

Comment: I get no error, but no grid system either.

Comment: Fixed! I had to add DOCTYPE to my html tag...<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: And for reference, the documentation details this requirement in the first point on the "Scaffolding" page - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html - But isn't actually explicit about it on the "Get Started" page (though the sample template *does* include the DOCTYPE declaration).

Comment: Argh. I thought that fixed it, but after looking again, the error is still there.